# My Toshiba Satellite c850 won't display screen

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-supply, battery, toshiba-laptop

Before this happened, I had some occurrences where my laptop's screen turned off out of no reason. Everything was still on (the sound, tasks in thr computer,  fan, etc. was working). I tried closing the lid and reopening it to lock the computer. That worked.

Today, I wanted to boot my laptop into safe mode as it kept on doing that. I ran `sfc /scannow`. After doing that, I decided to restart my computer to normal mode. But as it started to turn on, the screen was still blank. I thought it must be because my laptop was acting slow,  so I waited.  I heard the Windows 7 startup sound, but still couldn't see anything. The AC/battery, power and WIFI LED lights were still on and glowing. I typed in my password, and pressed enter. The login sound occured (which meant I was on the desktop), but the screen still didn't display anything.

I removed the battery and AC cord, held the power button for a few seconds, placed the battery back and the AC cord connected, and turned on my computer. Still, the same problem occured. Please help! I have no idea what made this happen. Maybe because a component/hardware piece went overheated (possibly a graphics card)? I don't want to dismantle my laptop as (I think) my warranty expired.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop's screen worked while you were in safe mode it's clearly not an issue with the monitor.

The issue can probably be with the video card which is overheating (the fan doesn't work anymore) or the video card just died on you. If another component overheated your laptop should power on, not just the screen.

You should try to dismantle it to check what's wrong with the video card.

Another quick idea would be to log in to your computer in safe mode and try to update the video driver.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score -2):

I have an HP laptop with similar problem. I believe the back lighting is bad. I can shine a flashlight (torch) on the screen and I can see the icons. I hooked the HDMI output to my television and the display is perfect. You problem might be the backlighting of your laptop display which requires surgery to repair. Might check this link at ehow.com.

[enter link description here](http://www.ehow.com/how_7189709_fix-laptop-screen-won_t-come.html#ixzz21bBUuMiG)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem but after dismantling the laptop i found out its a memory problem.try change the memory card

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).